# Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{corollary}

Tags: itemize

I have started writing an article using SIAM's macro package available [here](https://www.siam.org/publications/journals/about-siam-journals/information-for-authors#LaTex2e-Standard). However, I get the following error:

> line 18: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

with the following Tex content:

```
\documentclass{siamart190516}

\let\newtheoremstyle\relax
\let\newtheoremstyle\relax
\let\theoremstyle\relax
\let\theoremstyle\relax
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\section{xxx}
\begin{corollary} 
    Let $f$ be a function.
\end{corollary}
\end{document}
```

I do not have this error when using other document classes. Adding `\item` in the corollary section does not solve the issue.

Does anyone know what is happening? Is there a solution?

Comment: siamart190516 loads the ntheorem package - can you use its theorem capabilities in your application and avoid loading amsthm? If not, you could try `\PassOptionsToPackage{amsthm}{ntheorem}` right at the start to make ntheorem try being more compatible?

Comment: @AlexWatson Thanks, it worked. I have removed amsthm. Don't hesitate to create a solution.

Comment: Good to hear! I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

siamart190516 loads the [ntheorem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) package - if you don't load amsthm and use ntheorem's macros instead, you can avoid the issue.